# Azure Synapse SQL - alternative for recursive CTE

Tags: sql, azure, loops, common-table-expression, azure-synapse

I am making my first steps in Synapse.
I just learned that recursive CTEs cannot be executed, so I am looking for an alternative for this code:

```
with newFaktTableAllBoxesLabeled as (
    SELECT 
       m.[READ_TIME]
      ,m.[KYOTEN_CODE]
      ,m.[KOUTEI_CODE]
      ,m.[MAIN_EPC_DATA]
      ,m.[MAIN_HINSYU]
      ,m.[UNIT_EPC_DATA]
      ,m.[UNIT_HINSYU]
      ,m.[DENPYO_NO]
      ,m.[HIMO_FLG]
      ,m.[BOXID]
    FROM newFaktTableWithFirstBoxID m
    WHERE m.[UNIT_EPC_DATA] IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
         b.[READ_TIME]
        ,b.[KYOTEN_CODE]
        ,b.[KOUTEI_CODE]
        ,b.[MAIN_EPC_DATA]
        ,b.[MAIN_HINSYU]
        ,b.[UNIT_EPC_DATA]
        ,b.[UNIT_HINSYU]
        ,b.[DENPYO_NO]
        ,b.[HIMO_FLG]
        
        ,COALESCE(b.[BOXID], t.BOXID) as BOXID
    FROM newFaktTableAllBoxesLabeled t
    JOIN newFaktTableWithFirstBoxID b ON b.[UNIT_EPC_DATA] = t.[MAIN_EPC_DATA]
)
SELECT  * FROM newFaktTableAllBoxesLabeled
```

**Background Info**
Its a list with many boxes which get a new ID  every time they are relabled. I already identified the first occurence of a box and gave it an ID (BOXID). Now I would like to allocate this ID also to the same box after it had been relabled. I always know a box identifier ([MAIN_EPC_DATA]) and its future identifier ([UNIT_EPC_DATA]) in one row. So my goal is to reference the current ID to the former ID ([MAIN_EPC_DATA] to [UNIT_EPC_DATA]) and get the ID which I created already (BOXID) and which currently is only available for the first occurence of a box (so withouth a parent).

**Thats what the data looks like in a simplyfied way**
[what the data looks like now and what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdDdW.png)

I heard there is an option with a while loop, but I am not experienced enough to do that.
I would be very happy for your help!
Thank you!